# class member function return type

Tags: c++

I face a problem when I design a class;

```
class A
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A rhs);
public: 
    A do()
    { 
       A newobject;
       newobject = *this/2
       return newobject;
    }
private:
    vector<double>
}
```

assume I have an `A object{1.0,2.0,3.0}` then `object.do()` should be `{0.5,1.0,1.5}`

however when I want to print the result

```
A object
cout<<object<<object.do();
```

It causes an error, it seems that the `newobject` is deleted after calling the member function `object.do()`

And then I change the `do()` function

```
A& do()
{ 
   return *this/2
}
```

and then `cout<<object<<object.do();`
the result is `[0.5,1.0,1.5][0.5,1.0,1.5]`

the expected result should be `[1.0,2.0,3.0][0.5,1.0,1.5]`

I have some question:
1.How to get the expected result?
2.For the second `do()` function, why the `cout` result is `[0.5,1.0,1.5][0.5,1.0,1.5]`. `do()`function changed the member of object, but I `cout` `object` before call `object.do()`. I think the second case should get the expected result. I am wondering if something wrong with the overloaded `operator<<`or other part?

Comment: `cout<<A<<A.do();` cannot compile because `A` is the type name, not a variable. Please post the actual code.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And just saying that "it causes an error" without telling us *what* that error is, is kind of useless.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to creat an object of A. In fact,  it is not an error of complier. I mean the result is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

From

```
A& do()
{ 
   return *this/2
}
```

and your expectation to get `[0.5,1.0,1.5]` from `[1.0,2.0,3.0]`, I assume you want your class to wrap a vector that supports arithmetic operations? [Operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) is your friend. To give one more hint, if you overload operator `/` such that it divides the underlying vector values by rhs value, `do()` will do what you want. Moreover, you won't need `do()` anymore - you could call `cout << object/2` and it will print what you want. Try it.